# Converting Varchar to negative decimal in brackets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to change a String to a negative decimal value. The string is in the below format:
`($421.24)`

I want to change this `Varchar` to `decimal` to show either `-421.24` or `(421.24)`.
I am using `Replace` function to achieve that but that's not a cool way:

```
Select convert(decimal(18,2), Replace(Replace(Replace('($421.24)','$', '' ),'(','-'),')','')) -- output -421.24
```

I want to make it a general sql staement which holds true for both positive and negative numbers. Please suggest.

Comment: I think three nested `replace`s is the only way...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some shorter options:

1. Use a single replace to replace both the `(` and the `$` sign in one go:
   `Select CAST(Replace(Replace('($421.24)','($', '-'), ')', '') As decimal(18,2))`
2. Use substring instead of replace:
   `Select CAST('-' + SUBSTRING('($421.24)',3, LEN('($421.24)') - 3) As decimal(18,2))`
3. For SQL Server version 2017 or later, you can use [`translate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql), to replace multiple characters in a single command:
   `Select CAST(TRANSLATE('($421.24)', '($)', ' - ') As decimal(18,2))`

Answer (score 0):

Take the string and by using a `WHILE` loop, take each character and check whether it is a `.` or a number. If yes then take that character else neglect it and finally cast it to a decimal value.

**Query**

```
declare @str as varchar(100) = '($421.24)';
declare @len as int;
select @len = len(@str);
declare @i as int;
set @i = 1;
declare @res as varchar(100) = '';
while(@i <= @len)
begin
    declare @c as char(1);
    select @c = substring(@str, @i, 1);
    select @res+= case when ASCII(@c) = 46 or (ASCII(@c) between 48 and 57)
      then @c else '' end;

    set @i += 1;
end

select cast(@res as decimal(18, 2)) as [decimal_val];
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/782678/converting-varchar-to-negative-decimal-in-brackets)**

**Note:** You may need to check for multiple dots.

---

**Update**

If the string is in a format which cannot convert to a decimal value, then add the below after the `WHILE` loop.

**Query**

```
declare @isnum as bit;
select @isnum = isnumeric(@res);
if(@isnum = 1)
    select cast(@res as decimal(18, 2));
else 
    select 'String cannot convert to a decimal value.';
```

**[An other demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/782680/converting-varchar-to-negative-decimal-in-brackets-updated)**